# Non-compact and maximal non-$T_2$

Tags: general-topology

Is there a space $(X,\tau)$ that is not compact, not $T_2$, but for every topology $\tau'\supseteq \tau$ with $\tau'\neq\tau$ the space $(X,\tau')$ is $T_2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X$ be an infinite set and fix $a\neq b$ in $X$. Let $\tau$ be
the topology generated by the singletons $\{x\}$ for $x\neq a$ and
the set $\{a,b\}$. So every set $U\subset X$ is open, provided
that $a\in U\to b\in U$. This is not compact and not $T_2$, since
we cannot separate $a$ from $b$. But the only larger topology is
the discrete topology, which is $T_2$.